# mysql_fetch_assoc issue in while loop - wrong format of query in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, while-loop

I've foreach loop where in `$code` I get string number like this: 1234 4211 4223 2252 etc. although using explode or preg_split.

here is code

```
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {

    foreach ($tr as $td)

    $tdm = explode("/\s/", $td);
    $code = $tdm[0];

}


$sql_athl="SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `id`='$code'";
$results=mysql_query($sql_athl);
while($athl_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){

        echo $athl_info['NAT'];
}
```

As you can see I want to print mysql records where each number between space is an ID. I guess problem is with `$code` because `echo $sql_athl;` give me only

> SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `fiscode` =' 5451 4321 5142 5497
>   5253 6098 4322 '

instead of

> SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `fiscode` ='5451'
>   SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `fiscode` ='4321'

Any ideas or solutions guys?
I'm stuck...

Comment: since you have multiple codes you need to use `IN`  `WHERE fiscode IN (5451,4321,5142,5497,5253,6098,4322)`

Comment: show your `$rowData`(`var_dump($rowData)`)

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection

Comment: I don´t think `explode()` can handle Regex `/\s/`. So you should either use `explode(" " ...` or `preg_split('/\s/' ...`
There's other problems with your code too, i would take a good look at Noman's comment ant try to create a `WHERE ... IN` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First set your `code` variable as array.

```
$code = [];
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    foreach ($tr as $td) {
        $tdm = explode("/\s/", $td);
        $code[] = $tdm[0];
    }

}
```

Second add comma in array using `implode`.

```
$code = implode(",", $code);
```

Than add in `Mysql` quesry.

```
"SELECT * FROM grobar_IDs WHERE fiscode IN ('".$code."'");
```

Let me know if having any issue.

Comment: Almost work propely but Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/test.php on line 35

line35: `while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){` 

I used for query this string 
>SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `fiscode` IN ($code)

only on phpmyadmin work good

Comment: Check your `mysql` connection or give us your code.

Comment: First of all use `msqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`. B'coz `mysql_*` deprecated and may not available in future.

Comment: Although I change from mysql to mysqli and still had problem like before